# Secure share in samba not working, why?

Tags: shell, samba

The secure share that I created in samba with a password doesn't seem to work.

I have the following on my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` on a Linux Mint box(3.13.0-37-generic) box.

```
[myshare]            
comment = Home Directory  
path = /home/myshare
valid users = myshare
browseable = no           
public = no               
security = user           
readable = yes            
writable = yes            
guest ok = no
```

- The password for the user `myshare` is created using `smbpasswd -a myshare` and then enabled by `smbpasswd -e myshare`.
- The user is added using `useradd -c "myshare" -m -s /bin/false myshare` so that it doesn't have shell access

The `smb.conf` is:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP    
dns proxy = no
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes

security = user
encrypt passwords = yes

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000    
syslog = 0

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server

passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user

;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash
;   usershare max shares = 100

usershare allow guests = yes

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = %S

;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[myshare]
comment = Home Directory
path = /home/myshare
valid users = myshare
browseable = no
public = no
security = user
readable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
```

Now I tried restarting the `smbd` service but when I map the share on a Windows box, it just opens up without asking for any credentials.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
usershare allow guests = yes
```

I suspect the global value is overwriting.